# COM converting PPT to BMP but getting unreadable images

Tags: com, powerpoint, bmp

I need to transform a ppt file to BMP images in my application but  using  CopyEnhMetaFile() to my ppt object gives me images that are unreadable by applications such as Windows Photo Viewer .I have to point out that the windows paint utility(Windows 7) can view the files fine . Also ,on my test win xp virtual machine I notice that Windows Photo Viewer can open those BMP fine.

The code I use is shown below:

```
void PowerPointToPic(CString szDocName, CString szOutDir)
{

    CPPTApplication m_powerpointApp;
    CPPTPresentations m_powerpointPres;
    CPPTPresentation m_powerpointPre;
    CPPTSlide         slide;
    CPPTSlides       slides;
    m_powerpointPres.ReleaseDispatch();
    m_powerpointPre.ReleaseDispatch();


    try{
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        if(!m_powerpointApp.CreateDispatch(_T("PowerPoint.Application"), NULL))
        { 
            AfxMessageBox(_T("-------------------")); 
            return; 
        } 
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return;
    }

    m_powerpointApp.m_bAutoRelease=true;
    m_powerpointApp.put_Visible(long(1));
    m_powerpointApp.put_WindowState(long(2));
    m_powerpointPres.AttachDispatch(m_powerpointApp.get_Presentations());
    m_powerpointPres.Open(szDocName,TRUE, 1, 1);
    m_powerpointPre.AttachDispatch(m_powerpointApp.get_ActivePresentation(),TRUE);

    slides = m_powerpointPre.get_Slides();
    int pageCount = slides.get_Count();
    for( int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++ )
    {
        slide  = slides.Range(COleVariant((long)i));
        slide.Copy();
        if (::OpenClipboard(NULL)) 
        {
            //BOOL   ba=::IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_ENHMETAFILE); //
            BOOL   ba=::IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_LOCALE);

            HENHMETAFILE hEnhMetaFile = NULL;
            //CF_LOCALE
            //hEnhMetaFile = (HENHMETAFILE)GetClipboardData(CF_ENHMETAFILE); 
            hEnhMetaFile = (HENHMETAFILE)GetClipboardData(CF_LOCALE);
            if (hEnhMetaFile == NULL)
            {
                int err = GetLastError();
                m_powerpointApp.Quit();
                EmptyClipboard();
                CloseClipboard();
                return;
            }           

            CString temp;
            temp.Format(_T("%s-ppt-%d.bmp"), szOutDir, i);
        //HERE IS WHERE I SAVE MY METAFILE AS A BMP

            HENHMETAFILE   hMetaFile= CopyEnhMetaFile(hEnhMetaFile, temp);
            if (hMetaFile == NULL)
            {
                int err = GetLastError();
                m_powerpointApp.Quit();
                EmptyClipboard();
                CloseClipboard();
            }

            DeleteEnhMetaFile(hMetaFile); 
            EmptyClipboard();
            CloseClipboard(); 
        }

    }




    m_powerpointPre.Close();
    m_powerpointApp.Quit(); 
    m_powerpointPre.ReleaseDispatch();
    m_powerpointPres.ReleaseDispatch();
    slides.ReleaseDispatch();
    slide.ReleaseDispatch();
    m_powerpointApp.ReleaseDispatch();

    CoUninitialize();

}
```

I would appreciate any pointer.

Thank you for your time.

Edit:The Export method on the slide object saves .bmp images as I wish but can't do the same on word and excel as I can't figure out how to save ranges.Here is what I have tried.

```
void WordToPic(CString szDocName, CString szOutDir,QString outDir)
{
    _ApplicationWord WordApp; 
    Documents docs;   
    _Document   doc; 
    Selection   m_sel;
    Range rg;

    docs.ReleaseDispatch();
    m_sel.ReleaseDispatch();
    WordApp.m_bAutoRelease = true;
    try{
        if(CoInitialize(NULL) != 0)
            ;
        if(!WordApp.CreateDispatch(_T("Word.Application"),NULL))// 
        {   
            AfxMessageBox(_T("-----------------"));
            return ;   
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {       
        return;
    }

    COleVariant  varfilepath((LPCTSTR)szDocName);
    COleVariant  varstrnull(_T(""));
    COleVariant  covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND,VT_ERROR);
    COleVariant  vartrue((short)TRUE);
    COleVariant  varfalse((short)FALSE);

    docs.AttachDispatch(WordApp.GetDocuments());

    try{
        docs.Open(varfilepath,varfalse,vartrue,varfalse,   
            covOptional,covOptional,varfalse,covOptional,   
            covOptional,COleVariant(long(1)),covOptional,vartrue,covOptional,covOptional,covOptional,covOptional);
    }
    catch (...)
    {       
        Sleep(600);
        WordApp.Quit(covOptional,covOptional,covOptional);
        return;
    }

    doc.AttachDispatch(WordApp.GetActiveDocument());
    m_sel.AttachDispatch(WordApp.GetSelection());//
    m_sel.WholeStory();
    try {
        rg.AttachDispatch(doc.Range(COleVariant(long(0)),COleVariant(m_sel.GetEnd())));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        Sleep(600);
        WordApp.Quit(covOptional,covOptional,covOptional);
        return;
    }   
    long endDoc = rg.GetEnd(); 
    long start = 0;
    long end = 0; 

    m_sel.SetRange(endDoc,endDoc); 
    long countPage = ((LPVARIANT)COleVariant(m_sel.GetInformation(1) ) ) ->lVal;
    m_sel.SetRange(start,end); 

    int nCount = countPage;   
    CString picPath;
    int curNum=0;

    for (int num = 1; num<nCount+1; num++)//
    {
        curNum = num;
        if (num >1 )
        {           
            rg = m_sel.GoToNext( 1 );
            start = rg.GetStart();
        }
        if( num != countPage ) 
        { 
            rg = m_sel.GoToNext( 1 ); 
            end = rg.GetStart() - 1; 
        } 
        else 
            end = endDoc;

        m_sel.SetRange( start, end ); 
        rg = m_sel.GetRange();
        try
        {
            rg.CopyAsPicture();
            //SHOULD SAVE AS IMAGE  HERE.

        }
        catch (...)
        {
            WordApp.Quit(covOptional,covOptional,covOptional);
            return;
        }       


    }
    WordApp.Quit(covOptional,covOptional,covOptional);
    docs.ReleaseDispatch(); 
    m_sel.ReleaseDispatch();
    doc.ReleaseDispatch();
    rg.ReleaseDispatch();   
    WordApp.ReleaseDispatch();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

and for excel:

```
void ExcelToPic(CString szExcelName, CString szOutDir)
{
    _ApplicationExcel app;
    Workbooks books;
    _Workbook book;
    Worksheets sheets;
    _Worksheet sheet;
    RangeExcel range;
    RangeExcel iCell;
    LPDISPATCH lpDisp;   
    COleVariant vResult;
    COleVariant
        covTrue((short)TRUE),
        covFalse((short)FALSE),
        covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);          

    //*****
    if (CoInitialize(NULL)!=0) ;

    if(!app.CreateDispatch(_T("Excel.Application")))
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("-------------"));
        return ;
    }

    //app.SetVisible(TRUE); 
    app.SetUserControl(TRUE);     

    books.AttachDispatch(app.GetWorkbooks());
    lpDisp = books.Open((LPCTSTR)szExcelName,     
        covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional,
        covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional,
        covOptional, covOptional );     


    book.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);        


    sheets.AttachDispatch(book.GetWorksheets());

    long countPage = sheets.GetCount();


    RangeExcel usedRange;

    for(int i = 1; i < countPage+1; i++)
    {
        COleVariant vOpt((long)i);
        sheet = sheets.GetItem(vOpt);
        sheet.Activate();

        //*****

        usedRange.AttachDispatch(sheet.GetUsedRange());

        usedRange.Select();

        usedRange.CopyPicture(1,1);

        //SAVE AS IMAGE.
    }

    app.Quit();
    app.ReleaseDispatch();
    books.ReleaseDispatch();
    book.ReleaseDispatch();
    sheets.ReleaseDispatch();
    sheet.ReleaseDispatch();
    range.ReleaseDispatch();
    usedRange.ReleaseDispatch(); 

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can work with images on disk, the PowerPoint .Slide object has an .Export method that takes filename, export filter (in this case "BMP"), width, height as parms (width/height are in pixels).

I work in VB/VBA and may be misunderstanding what you're doing here, but it appears that you're putting an EMF format on the clipboard then saving it out with a BMP extension.

Kind of like putting a label that says "Sugar" on the salt shaker, isn't it?  ;-)

Comment: The Export method works.I need to do the same for word and excel but can't find a method similar to Export to save a whole word/excel page as an image .Is there a way I can do this?I included what I have tried in the edit to this question.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't know much about automating Word/Excel.